# Execute external jar file from pentaho

Tags: jar, pentaho, kettle

I am trying to execute a custom jar file from the modified javascript value. My Jar name is `JsonParsing.jar` which I have placed in lib folder. When I am trying to execute a method in the jar its giving me the error:

```
ReferenceError: "JsonParsing" is not defined.
```

Code Snippet:

```
var package1 = JsonParsing.parseJson.ParseJSON;
xyz=package1.processJson(data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue. I was missing the **Packages** thing while creating the instance. As I had a static method in my class I have to call it in the following way. (parseJson is my package name and ParseJSON is my class name) . Here **Packages** is the default class provided by Rhino

```
var call = Packages.parseJson.ParseJSON; 
xyz=call.processJson(data);
```

If it is a non static method I had to create an object in the following way

```
var call = new Pakages.parseJson.ParseJSON(); 
xyz=call.processJson(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Javascript kettle uses is Rhino. Rhino gives Javascript access to Java classes, but it's not completely transparent.

Check out the Rhino docs on [Scripting Java](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino/Scripting_Java).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried with "importPackage" and "importClass" methods. but no luck accessing the contents of a jar file. Is there any other way??

Comment: It should work if it's a standard jar. Can you import other packages like java.lang? Are you sure your jar is in the right location? It must be in the lib or libext folder of the Pentaho distribution. Your other option would be to use a `User defined java class`. This gives you more flexibility, but it's more work.